# What value does Postgres adapter for spark/hadoop add?

Tags: postgresql, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I am not an HDFS nerd but coming from traditional RDMS background, I am scratching surface with newer technologies like Hadoop and Spark. Now, I was looking at my options when it comes to SQL querying on Spark data.

What I realized that Spark inherently supports SQL querying. Then I came across this link

https://www.enterprisedb.com/news/enterprisedb-announces-new-apache-spark-connecter-speed-postgres-big-data-processing

Which I am trying to make some sense of. If I am understanding it correctly. Data is still stored in HDFS format but Postgres connector is used as a query engine? If so, in presence of an existing querying framework, what new value does this postgress connector add?

Or I am misunderstanding what it actually does?

Comment: did you find any value in this answer? If not, what have you found since yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding.

They allude to the concept of Foreign Data Wrapper.

"... They allow PostgreSQL queries to include structured or unstructured data, from multiple sources such as Postgres and NoSQL databases, as well as HDFS, as if they were in a single database. ...
"

This sounds to me like the Oracle Big Data Appliance approach. From Postgres you can look at the world of data processing it logically as though it is all Postgres, but underwater the HDFS data is accessed using Spark query engine invoked by the Postgres Query engine, but you need not concern yourself with that is the likely premise. We are in the domain of Virtualization. You can combine Big Data and Postgres data on the fly.

There is no such thing as Spark data as it is not a database as such barring some Spark fomatted data that is not compatible with Hive.

The value will be invariably be stated that you need not learn Big Data etc. Whether that is true remains to be seen.